# "ImportError: No module named pyaudio" despite python-pyaudio installed

Tags: 16.04, python, anki

I am trying to run a Python program that uses pyaudio:

1. I download the program ([from Github](https://github.com/dae/anki) because the .deb is too old)
2. I install `python-pyaudio`
3. I run the program
4. The program says `ImportError: No module named 'pyaudio'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
[sudo] password for nico: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python-pyaudio-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pyaudio
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/24.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 109 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyaudio.
(Reading database ... 336001 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-pyaudio_0.2.8-1build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-pyaudio (0.2.8-1build2) ...
Setting up python-pyaudio (0.2.8-1build2) ...

$ ./runanki 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runanki", line 3, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/home/nico/src/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from anki import version as _version
  File "/home/nico/src/anki/anki/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from anki.storage import Collection
  File "/home/nico/src/anki/anki/storage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from anki.collection import _Collection
  File "/home/nico/src/anki/anki/collection.py", line 26, in <module>
    from anki.sound import stripSounds
  File "/home/nico/src/anki/anki/sound.py", line 207, in <module>
    import pyaudio
ImportError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

Environment:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.11+
```

Comment: What does `which python` say?

Comment: Hmm, I initially thought you perhaps had your own Python installed in addition to the default one, so it couldn't see the `pyaudio` that was installed using `apt`. That doesn't seem to be what is happening here though.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I went to read the `runanki` script at https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/runanki and the shebang explicitly states Python 3. Are you sure `anki` will work for Python 2? If so, you could change the shebang to Python 2. The more straightforward solution in my opinion is to install the Python 3 version of `pyaudio` using `sudo apt install python3-pyaudio`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Would you mind posting an answer, including the shebang thing? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that the shebang of the `runanki` script at https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/runanki explicitly states Python 3, so `./runanki` invokes the Python 3 interpreter but you had installed `pyaudio` for Python 2. As a result, Python 3  is not able to find `pyaudio` and therefore raises an `ImportError`. The easiest solution here is to install the Python 3 bindings for `pyaudio` by running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pyaudio
```